# Is this a correct implementation of Merge Sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, divide-and-conquer

I'm currently learning about divide-and-conquer strategy for algorithms and figured that Merge Sort is a very good example that demonstrates the strategy.

I had some trouble understanding the concept thoroughly so I decided to try implementing it myself. I gave a go at it and I was wondering this is the correct implementation of the Merge Sort.

```cpp
vector<int> mergeSort(vector<int> n) {
    if(n.size() == 1) {
        return n;
    } else if(n.size() == 2) {
        vector<int> newVector;
        newVector.reserve(2);
        if(n[0] < n[1]) {
            newVector.push_back(n[0]);
            newVector.push_back(n[1]);
        } else {
            newVector.push_back(n[1]);
            newVector.push_back(n[0]);
        }
        return newVector;
    } else {
        int endIndexLeft = floor(n.size() / 2);
        int startIndexRight = ceil(n.size() / 2);

        vector<int>::const_iterator first = n.begin();

        // divide into 2 vectors
        vector<int> L(first, first + endIndexLeft + 1);
        vector<int> R(first + endIndexLeft + 1, first + n.size());

        // recursive call on each
        L = mergeSort(L);
        R = mergeSort(R);


        // combine the resulting array accordingly
        vector<int> sorted;
        sorted.reserve(n.size());

        int index_l = 0, index_r = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<n.size(); i++) {
            if(index_l == L.size()) {
                sorted.push_back(R[index_r]);
                index_r++;
            } else if(index_r == R.size()) {
                sorted.push_back(L[index_l]);
                index_l++;
            } else if(L[index_l] < R[index_r]) {
                sorted.push_back(L[index_l]);
                index_l++;
            } else {
                sorted.push_back(R[index_r]);
                index_r++;
            }
        }
        return sorted;
    }
}
```

After some testing, it seems like it generates the correct output (sorted vector in ascending order) but I wasn't sure if the implementation shows the use of divide-and-conquer strategy. Thanks in advance!

---

[EDIT: Realized that I don't even need the `n.size() == 2` part so I got rid of that and seperated out the merge function.]

```cpp
vector<int> mergeVector(vector<int> L, vector<int> R) {
    vector<int> combined;
    combined.reserve(L.size() + R.size());

    int index_l = 0, index_r = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<L.size() + R.size(); i++) {
        if(index_l == L.size()) {
            combined.push_back(R[index_r]);
            index_r++;
        } else if(index_r == R.size()) {
            combined.push_back(L[index_l]);
            index_l++;
        } else if(L[index_l] < R[index_r]) {
            combined.push_back(L[index_l]);
            index_l++;
        } else {
            combined.push_back(R[index_r]);
            index_r++;
        }
    }

    return combined;
}

vector<int> mergeSort(vector<int> n) {
    if(n.size() == 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        int endIndexLeft = floor(n.size() / 2);

        vector<int>::const_iterator first = n.begin();

        // divide into 2 vectors
        vector<int> L(first, first + endIndexLeft);
        vector<int> R(first + endIndexLeft, first + n.size());

        // recursive call on each
        L = mergeSort(L);
        R = mergeSort(R);


        // combine the resulting arrays
        vector<int> sorted;
        sorted.reserve(n.size());
        sorted = mergeVector(L,R);

        return sorted;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't check indices, but overall idea (and divide-and-conquer strategy implementation) is correct.

Comment: When recursively splitting the left side and right side you are performing the divide part. When you are merging them back together, you are performing the conquer part. There are some improvements that could be done on the splitting part though, because this is array based you can calculate middle, split list by middle and recursive sort and merge that

Comment: @EvenStensberg I realized that I don't even need the `n.size() == 2` part so I removed that and changed the splitting part a little bit! Let me know if that's a bit better.

Comment: The `floor` function in `floor(n.size() / 2)` is unnecessary. Integer division already truncates the result (rounds towards zero) and the `floor` function just converts it into a double, floors it, then returns the result as a double which is then converted back into an int by truncating.

Comment: `first + n.size()` is the same as `n.end()`. You don't need to explicitly use `reserve` for the `sorted` vector. Just do `return mergeVector(L,R)`. Even if you were to store the return value of `mergeVector`, you could just do `vector<int> sorted = mergeVector(L,R)` which should allocate the memory efficiently.

Comment: @FeiXiang Will keep those in mind in the future. Thank you very much for the feedback!

Comment: This might be more appropriate at [codereview.se] since you have a working program, just beware that there are specific rules you have to follow when posting there.